# How to construct a route model binding url with axios?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to write a vue Axios URL with slug and id, but I can't.

Please help me.

```js
axios.get('http://localhost/BUproject/postsByUser/' + slug / +id)
    .then(response => {
        this.postsByUser = response.data;
        Vue.filter('myOwnTime', function (value) {
            return moment(value).fromNow();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from your code the placement of the quotes and `+` is not quite adding up properly.

You can do good old fashioned string concatenation:

```
'http://localhost/BUproject/postsByUser/' + slug + '/' +id'
```

Or if using ES6, you can do

```
`http://localhost/BUproject/postsByUser/${slug}/${id}`
```

Also if the call will always be to the same server as you are working in, you can ditch the `http://localhost` part to make it relative to the root.

```
`/BUproject/postsByUser/${slug}/${id}`
```

[All you ever wanted to know about String in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)